# Share URL with SMS, Email, Messager, WhatsApp, Facebook, and Twitter

Tags: html, share

Here is what I'm doing but most are broken:

```html
<div class="flex gap-2 mb-4">
  <a
    class="button bg-white button--sms"
    href="sms:?body=dedewdwed+https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fevents%2Fdedewdwed"
    >SMS</a
  ><a
    class="button bg-white button--email"
    href="mailto:?subject=dedewdwed&amp;body=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fevents%2Fdedewdwed"
    >Email</a
  ><a
    class="button bg-white button--messenger"
    href="http://www.facebook.com/dialog/send?app_id=207071674345536&amp;message=dedewdwed&amp;link=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fevents%2Fdedewdwed&amp;redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000"
    >Messenger</a
  >
</div>
<div class="flex gap-2 mb-4">
  <a
    class="button bg-white button--whatsapp"
    href="https://wa.me/?text=dedewdwed+https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fevents%2Fdedewdwed"
    >WhatsApp</a
  ><a
    class="button bg-white button--facebook"
    href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?quote=dedewdwed&amp;u=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fevents%2Fdedewdwed"
    >Facebook</a
  ><a
    class="button bg-white button--twitter"
    href="http://twitter.com/share?text=dedewdwed&amp;url=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fevents%2Fdedewdwed"
    >Twitter</a
  >
</div>
```

[image: share]

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Hi Dorian, please be more specific, what is broken with the buttons? How are most of them broken?

Comment: sms puts the url as the recipient (ios), email has + for spaces in subject line, messenger has 4202 error from m.facebook.com, whatsapp works fine, facebook works fine, twitter works fine